# WARN - Insufficient threads configured for SelectChannelConnector

Tags: centos7, carrot2

I am using carrot2 search server on centos 7. But when i want to run dcs.sh file it produces `[WARN] insufficient threads configured for SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080`.

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: I am using this command for running dcs ...  bash dcs.sh

Comment: I am using carrot2 version : carrot2-dcs-3.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a version error.

i have face the same issue but i fix it after installing the new version of carret2 server.

install this version carrot2-dcs-3.15.1.

Comment: No problem most wellcome